# How can I get a plugin for neo4j 3.4.5 with gremlin console or server?

Tags: neo4j, maven-plugin, gremlin

I intend to use the Neo4j-community database in version **3.4.5** with Gremlin commands.

But I tried getting plugins but none are working for the later versions of neo4j.

Can someone outline how I can resolve my requirements?

Comment: Minor formatting, tried to add a more precise question within the scope of the community.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, TinkerPop's `neo4j-gremlin` is built to work with Neo4j 3.2.3. That dependency is set via:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl/blob/0.7-3.2.3/pom.xml#L23

To see an upgrade, that library would need to be bumped to the version of Neo4j that you want and then `neo4j-gremlin` would need to be updated in TinkerPop:

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.3.3/neo4j-gremlin/pom.xml#L120

Obviously I don't know if there would be required code changes in either repository for this to work.